# Java jdbc cannot Insert to database

Tags: java, sql-server, resultset

I have 2 classes ConnectionUtil, DemoResultSet. The problem is when I run **insert 2 times()**.Then just only 1 record is inserted to database. The second insert create error: `"Error:The connection is closed."`. So when I uncomment `close() statement`. It run nice. I don't know what is the trouble. Anyone give me some idea

```
public class ConnectionUtil {

    private static String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Northwind";
    private static String username = "user";
    private static String pw = "pass";
    private static Connection conn = null;

    static {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ConnectionUtil.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        if (conn == null) {
            try {
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, pw);
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ConnectionUtil.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        return conn;
    }
}

public class DemoResultSet {

    private static ResultSet rs = null;
    private static Connection conn = null;

    public static void initialize() {
        try {
            conn = ConnectionUtil.getConnection();
            Statement statement = conn.createStatement( ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE );
            String sql = "select CategoryID, CategoryName from Categories";
            rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DemoResultSet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        initialize();
        insert();
        insert();
    }

    public static void insert() {
        try {
            rs.moveToInsertRow();
            rs.updateString("CategoryName", "Test C1008G3");
            rs.insertRow();
            System.out.println("Inserted");
            conn.close(); //uncomment it's okay
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error:" + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are closing your connection inside the insert, so the second insert happens on a closed connection.

The conn.close(), should really be placed like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    try{
        initialize();
        insert();
        insert();
    }
    finally{
        conn.close();
    }
}
```

So that you can guarantee the connection is closed properly in the event of any problems.

Answer (score 0):

in your insert method you have `conn.close(); //uncomment it's okay`

But its not!

After you have closed this connection you do not open it again.

Answer (score 0):

the jdbc connection is a somewhat heavy object and the idea behind it is not not close it after every operation, but rather reuse the connection for multiple tasks. you should close your connection when your application is done. If you insist on own connections, you have to re-initialize after every close.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you are trying to write to a Connection after closing said connection.
you can uncomment that line, but that's just bad practice.
my advice: call the initialize(); method not from inside the main method, but as first statement in the insert method.

that way, you are sure you have the connection every time you need it.

Comment: It show: Oct 01, 2013 4:34:20 PM ResultSetDemo.DemoResultSet initialize
Error:The connection is closed.
SEVERE: null